# how to reopen the side-menu in react-native

Tags: react-native

native-side-menu, ,In my menu.js file,when i click on text side menu as to closed and new component as to be show,upto that part my code working,But what my problem is that when i press on button side menu as reopen again there my code not working,i am struggling there 
here is my code is like this:

```
Place(){
    this.props.getNavigator().push({
      component:Place,
      title:’ Place',
      leftButtonIcon: require('image!settings3'),
      onLeftButtonPress: ()=> {this.refs.sidemenu.openMenu()},//here i am getting confusion that how to reopen my sidemenu//
    });
}
render(){
return(
<ScrollView>
<TouchableOpacity getNavigator={this.props.getNavigator} onPress={this.Place.bind(this)}>
                      <Image style={styles.avatar} source={require('image!location')}/>
                      <Text style={styles.name}>Place</Text>
               </TouchableOpacity>
</ScrollView>
)
}
```

what i want is when i press on leftButtonIcon again i want reopen the side-menu any help must be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In native-side-menu, we have to use menuActions to control the side-menu
in this case use `this.context.menuActions.open()`

You can check https://github.com/Kureev/react-native-side-menu#managing-menu-state
for detailed documentation on menuActions

Comment: i mean that when i close the slide menu,i.e inside the menu i used some text when click on that text it renders new component,there also i need the slide menu as like before,But i wrote the navigator.push in the menu only

Comment: have you tried bubbling up this interaction to the parent/ to the component where the menu exists